# View Not Showing Updated Property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM and am having trouble with a simple text binding. Here is my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.ViewModels.SupportArchiveDialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;assembly=MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid Margin="16">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SupportArchivePath}" Margin="0 5 0 0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsCancel="True" Margin="0 10 0 0" Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                Command="{x:Static wpf:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}">
            OK
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and my viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Project.ViewModels;
using MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;

namespace Project
{
    public class DialogViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _supportArchivePath;

    public string SupportArchivePath
    {
        get { return _supportArchivePath; }
        set
        {
            this.MutateVerbose(ref _supportArchivePath, value, RaisePropertyChanged());
        }
    }

    public async void ExecuteRunDialog(object o)
    {

        var view = new SupportArchiveDialog
        {
            DataContext = new DialogViewModel()               
        };

        //show the dialog
        var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ClosingEventHandler);

    }

    private void ClosingEventHandler(object sender, DialogClosingEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Action<PropertyChangedEventArgs> RaisePropertyChanged()
    {
        return args => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
}
```

}

and lastly my implementation (this code block is run in the code behind of my mainwindow):

```
        DialogViewModel dvm = new DialogViewModel();
        dvm.SupportArchivePath = archivePath;
        dvm.ExecuteRunDialog(null);
```

I'd expect that the text in the view bound to property "SupportArchivePath" would update when I set the property's value as above. However, the textblock is empty when I run my project. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: Sounds like `RaisePropertyChanged()` is not getting triggered. If you just call it on its  own right after `this.MutateVerbose(...)` inside the setter, does that make it work?

Comment: Failure to update can be any number of things. You should start by debugging. Look at the debugger output to see if any errors were emitted by WPF. Then if that looks okay, set breakpoints and step through the code to see at what point the binding fails; it can be that the property was not set the way you expected it, or that nothing has subscribed to the event (indicating a binding syntax problem), or that the event isn't raised correctly (either not raised at all, or raised with the wrong property name).

Comment: Since you didn't provide a good [mcve] (the `MutateVerbose()` method, arguably the most important one here, is missing), it's not practical to try to write an actual answer to the question.

Comment: I will point out that the other thing missing from your code example is any indication that you've set the data context to your view model object. Again, it's not clear whether you just didn't bother to include that part of the code, or you are in fact _missing_ that crucial step in the binding. And again, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to say for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Since we cannot check the code of MutateVerbose that you defined in your extension, you can [check here](https://dragablz.net/2015/12/14/viewmodelbase-go-away/) if you are doing well.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was instantiating a new instance of my viewmodel right before presentation - AFTER I had already set the property, that's why I never saw the property change. The fix was to change this:

```
    DialogViewModel dvm = new DialogViewModel();
    dvm.SupportArchivePath = archivePath;
    dvm.ExecuteRunDialog(null);
```

and this

```
   public async void ExecuteRunDialog(object o)
   {

    var view = new SupportArchiveDialog
    {
        DataContext = new DialogViewModel()               
    };

    //show the dialog
    var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ClosingEventHandler);

   }
```

to this

```
DialogViewModel dvm = new DialogViewModel();
dvm.SupportArchivePath = archivePath;
dvm.ExecuteRunDialog(dvm);
```

and this

```
public async void ExecuteRunDialog(object o)
{
  var view = new SupportArchiveDialog
  {
      DataContext = o              
  };

//show the dialog
var result = await DialogHost.Show(view, "RootDialog", ClosingEventHandler);

}
```